# Select target of link

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I have a list of six links to on page anchors and I want to animate the scroll to them.

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><a href="#one">One</a></td>
<td><a href="#two">Two</a></td>
<td><a href="#three">Three</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="#four">Four</a></td>
<td><a href="#five">Five</a></td>
<td><a href="#six">Six</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

$("#nav a").click(function(){

// Disable the default behaviour when a user clicks an empty anchor link.
 // (The page jumps to the top instead of // animating)
 event.preventDefault();

// Animate the scrolling motion.
 $("html, body").animate({
scrollTop:this.attr('target').offset().top
 },"slow");
});

});
```

This does not work, I get an error saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object http://url/#one has no method 'attr'
```

So obviously I need to rewrite this line:

```
scrollTop:this.attr('target').offset().top
```

But how do I select the target of the link to find the offset so I can set the scroll height?

SOLUTION:

Final answer was that there were a few things wrong, probably most notable was the missing $ as pointed out below.  Here is the code I settled on using:

```
$("#nav a").click(function(){

// Disable the default behaviour when a user clicks an empty anchor link.
 // (The page jumps to the top instead of // animating)
 event.preventDefault();

// Animate the scrolling motion.
 $("html, body").animate({
scrollTop:($("[name='"+ (this.hash).replace('#', '') +"']").offset().top)
 },"slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting that error is because you haven't wrapped your element in jQuery (you have other bugs in your code too).

However, that's not even needed. You want to use the contents of the `href` attribute as an ID selector:

```
$("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(this.href).offset().top
}, "slow");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  However, that gives me this error:Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

Comment: @TegRyan - Does it tell you where that error occurs? It's definitely not in the code in my answer.

Comment: oh weird, you're right.  it's in the jquery code itself.  Version 1.8.3.  I'd paste the line, but it's minified so line 2 is essentially the whole API.

Comment: Also, I should have specified.  That jQuery code is a snippet from a larger piece that is wrapped.  Edit:  Added the wrapper